# C# excel data validation drop down list throwserror

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I'm trying to add drop down list to a range using c#.

This is what I have done so far.

```
 Worksheet ws = PPTAddIn.thisAddin2Obj.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
            ws.get_Range("a1").Validation.Delete();
            ws.get_Range("a1").Validation.InCellDropdown = true;
            ws.get_Range("a1").Validation.IgnoreBlank = true;
            ws.get_Range("a1").Validation.Add(XlDVType.xlValidateList, XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertWarning, "opt1,opt2,opt3", Missing.Value);
```

at 3rd line of code it throws below exception 
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

[image: ErrorImage]

this is the stack trace

```
   at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)    at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Validation.set_InCellDropdown(Boolean ) at MS.ProductionPlanningTool.Excel.Ribbon_PPT.ribbon_signin_Click(Object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e) in D:\MidasCloud\CloudTFS\ProductionPlanning\MSP2\MS.ProductionPlanningTool.Excel\UI\Ribbon_PPT.cs:line 1328    at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonPropertyStorage.ControlActionRaise(IRibbonControl control)    at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonPropertyStorage.ButtonClickCallback(RibbonComponentImpl component, Object[] args)    at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonManagerImpl.Invoke(RibbonComponentCallback callback, Object[] args)    at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)    at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonManagerImpl.System.Reflection.IReflect.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] args, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParameters)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sequence of commands is incorrect.  Move the `Add` statement to be immediately after the `Delete` statement.  You can not set the other values on the `Validation` object if a validation does not exist.

```
Worksheet ws = PPTAddIn.thisAddin2Obj.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
ws.get_Range("a1").Validation.Delete();
ws.get_Range("a1").Validation.Add(XlDVType.xlValidateList, XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertWarning, "opt1,opt2,opt3", Missing.Value);
ws.get_Range("a1").Validation.InCellDropdown = true;
ws.get_Range("a1").Validation.IgnoreBlank = true;
```

**Side Note:**

Use the macro recorder in Excel to get the syntax for an operation.  While the output is in VBA, the syntax is not that different that you can not decipher the commands and translate to C#.  VBA is close enough VB.Net that a VB to C# converter will yield code that you can clean up and use.  The only issue will be that the macro-recorder makes extensive use of the `Selection` object and you should convert that to whatever the `Selection` object represents (most likely it is an `Excel.Range`).  You will also need to make the corrections for VB's indexed properties to the equivalent method calls (i.e.: `Range("a1")` -> `get_Range("a1")`).

**Edit:**  I originally did not check the syntax of your `Add` statement, but it appears that you are missing a parameter.

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.validation.add.aspx):

```
void Add(
    XlDVType Type,
    Object AlertStyle,
    Object Operator,
    Object Formula1,
    Object Formula2
)
```

and your `Add` staterment:

```
Add(XlDVType.xlValidateList, 
    XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertWarning, 
    "opt1,opt2,opt3", 
    Missing.Value)
```

It appears the you are missing the `Operator` parameter.  Using the macro recorder, it appears that the default value is `XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween`.

You should also define a `Validation` object and use that instead of `ws.get_Range("a1").Validation` for setting/calling each property/method.

Comment: I cannot check now if this is right, but +1 for the advice on how to get the VBA code as a guide. OP, Many VBA developers do this for bits of the Object Model which we have forgotten. It is a decent starting point for amendment...

Comment: @TnTinMn, you missed to pass value for operator parameter. In my case it's Missing.Value. I was getting exception until I figured it out.

Comment: Another thing to note: the worksheet must be unprotected to add data validation (even if the protection is UserInterfaceOnly). This was my issue

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your ".InCellDropDown = true" to the end of the code.

I mean:

```
 Worksheet ws = PPTAddIn.thisAddin2Obj.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
            ws.get_Range("a1").Validation.Delete();
            ws.get_Range("a1").Validation.IgnoreBlank = true;
            ws.get_Range("a1").Validation.Add(XlDVType.xlValidateList, XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertWarning, "opt1,opt2,opt3", Missing.Value);
            ws.get_Range("a1").Validation.InCellDropdown = true;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It doesn't work then exception throws at ignoreblank line,
I tried moving ignoreblank line to the end then it throws at add method. It continues to throw the same exception.

Comment: Hi Roland,
Is there any other way to add drop down list to a cell?
any idea would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the accepted answer for getting me most of the way there, but alas it didn't work first off. There was a missing paramater, as Jayakrishnan correctly points out in the comments under that answer. Because future visitors like me may not look at those comments for a while, I'll post my code here. My code shows the usage of named parameters to skip over the optional operator parameter. It also shows how to add data validation as a function taking any list of strings (I just do a .join beforehand!). Enjoy.

```
public void SetDropdownValidation(params string[] values)
{
    string valuesJoined = string.Join(",", values);
    Validation validation = RawRange.Validation;
    validation.Delete();
    validation.Add(XlDVType.xlValidateList, XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertWarning, Formula1: valuesJoined, Formula2: Missing.Value);
    validation.InCellDropdown = true;
}
```

### Notes

- This function is written in the context of a class where `RawRange` is a member variable of type `Range`.
- This code could be tweaked / made more flexible to deal with stuff like IgnoreBlank, but the basic idea is in the above

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look at this, it might help you:

(focus on the Part 2 - Restrict Entry to Predefined Items in a List)

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1089368/Apply-Data-Validation-to-Excel-Cells-in-Csharp